# Problema com JavascriptExecutor Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Não consigo executar a função `doFilterOffer()` na pagina, ele da o seguinte erro

> missing ; before statement

, qual o problema com esta sintaxe abaixo?

```
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("Function doFilterOffer();", "click");
    }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar uma parte maior do código? O erro é indicado antes do if ou após entrar nele?

Comment: @mauriciocaserta ja resolvi, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava no uso do parâmetro `Function`

O correto é:

> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("doFilterOffer();",
>   "click");